# Core data fetch data which actually stored in persistentStore not all objects of entities (persistentStored + latest created obj)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have one entity name is **student** and I want fetch those student data which lives in Pune city **(city == pune)**. In table there are **2** students who lives in **pune city**.

But before that I have create **new student object who lives also in pune** city.

**So when I fire fetch request on student entity its give me 3 student data which included my current student data also (2 from table and 1 which I just created not saved in table)**

**So my question is I just want only those student data which I actually
stored in persistence data not those which are just created.**

```
Entity data (student)
--------------------------------------------------------
student name       city         class
--------------------------------------------------------
Atul               pune           7
Sagar              mumbai         7
Ganesh             pune           7
--------------------------------------------------------
```

current object

```
Student * obj = [[Mlov alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


    obj.name = @"Nitin";
    obj.city = @"pune";
    obj.class = 10;
     NSError * error = nil;

    NSPredicate * pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"city == 'pune'"];


    NSFetchRequest * req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Student"];
    [req setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    [req setPredicate:pred];
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSArray * result =[context executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];
    for (Student * obj in result)
    NSLog(@"%@",obj.name);
```

---

```
Expected output as only 2 students data (Atul and Ganesh)

Actually giving output as 3 students data (Atual, Ganesh and Nitin)
```

I need to fetch those student data which are stored in persistence store, If you have any suggestion please let me know. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could filter out objects which appear in the context's `insertedObjects` property.  `[result filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF NOT IN %@", context.insertedObjects]];`.

Comment: Is there another way for that while fetching data from core data not after getting it.

Comment: Yep.  Create a new context.  It won't be able to fetch anything that is not the persistent store (or the parent context, if you use that setup).

Comment: [result filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF NOT IN %@", context.insertedObjects]]; -> its crashing "the format string "SELF NOT IN %@" also I just NSStringWithFormat then also its crashed

Comment: Sorry, I always make that mistake.  Correct format: `NOT SELF IN %@`.

Comment: @Avi can you please post it as answer so I vote it up, Thanks its working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96665/discussion-between-pravin-tate-and-avi).

Comment: Did you try using `req.includesPendingChanges = NO`? (See docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/includesPendingChanges))

Comment: @pbasdf: hey its working thanks :) , can you send me some useful links related for core data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You could filter out objects which appear in the context's insertedObjects property.

```
[result filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT SELF IN %@",
                                                                     context.insertedObjects]];
```

**Solution 2**

Use a fresh context for the query.